# Propagate event to entire object

Tags: qt, events, tree, window

I just recently started exploring Qt (version 5 at the moment) and I came across an issue to which I could not find any solution:

I would like to send a custom event to the main window such that the event is then propagated to the entire object tree (given by `QObject::dumpObjectTree()`). Then, certain parts of the object tree can choose to react to the event.

Is there a method to do so in Qt?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for (a kind of broadcast event) does not exist in Qt. Events are targeted to specific objects.

Signals are closer to what you want. You can generate a signal without specifying who it's for. Then any other object is able to connect a slot to that signal if it's interested in it.

Comment: Is it possible to connect more than one slot to a signal?

Comment: Yes, you can connect as many slots as you want to the same signal.